# MYSQL - Check conflicting time

Tags: mysql

Currently, I have this table 'tbl_subloading' :

```
teacher_name  |  start_time   |  end_time  
de Guzman, J  |  08:00AM      |  10:00AM
Harris, M     |  07:00AM      |  09:00AM
```

What I want is my program to detect if schedule given to a certain teacher overlaps his/her existing schedule already. For example, 'de Guzman, J' could no longer have any class from 9am-11am since he is no longer available.

I tried this query that I saw coming from a different thread:

```
SELECT (COUNT(*) = 0) AS Available FROM tbl_subloading 
WHERE `teacher_name` = 'de Guzman, J' 
AND ( (start_time <= '07:00AM' AND end_time >= '07:00AM') 
OR (start_time <= '08:00AM' AND end_time >= '08:00AM'));
```

This query outputs 1 if he is available for that certain period, 0 if not. 
For example, if de Guzman, J is given a schedule from 12pm to 1pm, it outputs 1. But if de Guzman, J is given a schedule from 10am to 11am, it outputs 0 although he is already available for that period.

Is there any alternative you could do from this?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5):

You can user `BETWEEN` to simplify the query.

```
 SELECT (COUNT(*)) AS Available 
 FROM tbl_subloading 
 WHERE teacher_name = 'de Guzman, J' 
 AND ( (start_time BETWEEN '07:00AM' AND '08:00AM') OR (start_time BETWEEN '08:00AM' AND '09:00AM'))
```

If de Guzman, J is not occupied between the given time periods, the output will be 0. Otherwise,based on the time slots you provide, it will be a positive integer value like 1,2. You can add many time slots by providing an `OR` condition.

Note that `BETWEEN` is inclusive.So your time slot starting and end values along with the values in between will be considered as well.

Comment: Still doesn't work on me. It provides 0 even though he is no longer available on that time period.

Comment: Try it with a mySQL compliant date format like this.

start_time BETWEEN '2010-01-30 14:15:55' AND '2010-09-29 10:15:55'